# On Windows 10 Make Inno Setup Uninstall Not Use Programs and Features Control Panel

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

On Windows 10, I created an Inno Setup install that loads the program just fine. However, when I go to uninstall the program ( start menu right-click choose uninstall) it opens the Program and Features control panel and then I have to choose the program I want to uninstall a second time.

How do I code the Inno Setup Script so it automatically starts the uninstall process without opening the Program and Features control panel and making me select the program I want to uninstall a second time?

Comment: That's a standard behavior for all desktop applications. Even Microsoft applications (e.g. VS2015) behave this way. Do you have any reason believe that it's customizable?

Comment: I'm remembering that uninstalls used to just fire off after a confimation dialog and didn't open the add/remove programs control panel. Is this new bahavior since Windows 7?

Comment: The right-click *Uninstall* command in the Start menu is new in Windows 10, afaik. It does directly uninstall the "apps" only. For desktop applications it opens Program and Features control panel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Exec or Exec2 I don't remember what is it called but it goes something like this :
Exec('{app}/unistall00.exe')

Sorry I can't elaborate much since i'm on a mobile and you can also see in the Documentation.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is about the standard "Uninstall" command in Windows 10 Start menu.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Well I didn't wanted to answer but to Comment it but I guess I can't find the Comment button in the Android App. But also he said that how could i code it into the Inno Setup script, I guess that's how it can help him..

Comment: *"I can't find the Comment button in the Android App"* - That does not justify you breaking the rules! - And your answer does not make sense - How would you make Windows execute your Pascal Script code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You didn't get what I tried to say, I didn't wanted to answer but to Comment my thought, but there's no function in the Android app to do so.. And also #Gunny have asked that "How do he could code it into inno setup?" also I'm sorry for any misunderstanding..

Comment: I believe I got what you meant. Again, the fact that there's no comment function in Android app, does not justify you breaking the rules by posting your comment as an answer - Though actually I'm pretty sure the comment function is there. But you do not have a privilege to comment yet. Gather some reputation first!

Comment: @PRince4 Stack Overflow is very strict with new users. You get the privilege to comment everywhere when you reach 50, this is done on purpose to avoid and/or combat spam. My suggestion would be to participate and answer questions (most of the time also write some short example code or Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE))

Comment: @RemziCavdar Yeah, I learned the hard way 5 years ago. XD

Comment: @PRince4 Yeah, I see  My comment was late lol 